# Smart GWT listgrid, how to expand and row span at the same time

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

So I have a Smart GWT ListGrid and I want to be able to make the rows expandable and at the same time do a row span on them. Expanding rows which are not merged (by doing row span) works fine, however if I have several rows that are merged the expand icon disappears. My code for expanding and row spanning is this:

```
lisgrid = new LisGrid()
{
    @Override
protected Canvas getExpansionComponent(final ListGridRecord record)
{
    // Add a nested grid to display the remaining requests for the tag
    // (after the first N being shown be default).
    VLayout layout = new VLayout(5);
    layout.setPadding(1);

    final ExtendedListGrid requestGrid = new ExtendedListGrid();
    requestGrid.setWidth(500);
    requestGrid.setHeight(224);
    requestGrid.setCellHeight(22);
    requestGrid.setDataSource(datasource);
    requestGrid.fetchData();

    layout.addMember(requestGrid);

    return layout;
}
};

listGrid.setAllowRowSpanning(true);
listGrid.setCanExpandRecords(true);
listGrid.setMergeCols(new String[] { "requestSummaryTagId", "gca" });
```

I have overridden the getRowSpan method of the ListGrid to span a cell until the cell right under (same column index and next row index) it has the same value, and I also have a method, setMergeCols, that tells the grid which cells to span across rows. Here is what it looks like. As you can see, the first 2 cells at the bottom span 4 rows, but the expand symbol is missing, while for the rows above (which don't have any row span) the expand symbol is there. Any idea why?

[image]